# shelf и работа с ним

Tags: link, vi, qnx

ОС - QNX 6.5.0 хочу отредактировать файл 
/$DirRoot/.ph/shelf/shelf.cfg
вопрос заключается в том, как это можно сделать из командной строки?(помимо vi редактора)(не знаю в тему ли информация, однако через mqc открыть его для редакции не получилось, пишет, что файл бинарный, нельзя редактировать)
Есть ли опция создать свой файл File.cfg и сделать внутри shelf.cfg ссылку, которая будет забирать код(конфигурацию) из моего cfg файла?

Comment: ладно, немного изменю поставленную задачу. можно ли в qnx с помощью vi редактора сделать замену по типу команды 
" sed 's|abc|bcd|g' "
заменяющий абс на бсд?

Comment: Ладно, я понял, что не графическими средствами поменять шелф будет весьма проблематично, если вообще реально. Чтоб лишний раз не маячить закрываю тему.